# OOP in gui testautomation scripts

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, automation

I'm working on a test automation for a web gui. It's a large product so it's important to design a good software architecture. First i have decided to isolate test data from test logic. After that i want to build classes in oop style which helps to handle changes in short time.

I have the following gui design:
[image]

I think i should isolate the menu, navigation and toolbar in extra classes, because so there is only one place to handle changes. I don't know if it is the best way to handle it. Are there other options to deal with?

PS: I'm using Squish Gui Test  Automation Tool with python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i'm using an abstraction layer between web application and test logic. The test developer only use methods from abstraction classes. 
The advantage is that no test developer have to understand the structure of the web application.

After 4 weeks of work with this layer it's possible to create and handle our tests really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at Django?
Edit: I interpreted from the 1st paragraph that the OP was going to roll his own oop gui web framework.

Comment: Care to elaborate how this is relevant to OP's question?

Comment: @GSP I think it's an oop question, because i want to improve my oop architecture and want to know if there is a better way to isolate gui parts.

Comment: @John Thank you for your answer but i didn't need a framework to handle oop. I need "philosophy" to handle gui parts in an automation.

Comment: @Sentencio: Note the difference between OOP and OP, the latter stands for Original Poster. I was surprised by this answer, i.e. how can Django framework be relevant to testing an unspecified web app?

Comment: @GSP aaah i see it. I was thinking about a typo ... ^^

Answer (score 0):

What we use as "automation design" is to automate certain blocks. Each test scenario is built out of logical blocks (sub scenario's). Logon, fill form 1, fill form 2, report outcome, close application. These are the items we automate and with the correct set of parameters, you can automate all scenario's.

The way you automate, also a good idea (have done this also). 
Each section is a block also. Each block can be called for and with the correct parameters, the tester can make a scenario
Blok1(editbox1, "the text"; editbox2, "") etc..

Where to think about, how do you represent this to the functional testers? 
Will they understand the way of working? (some testers are even scared of XML... so, make it simple.)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was, grouping functions together based on the area of the GUI they relate. For instance, in your example, you have 4 major sections. If we take "Optional tool bar" section, you can define a separate function group for that section and add all sub functions under that main function.

For example, in JavaScript you can do something like below:

```
var OptionalToolbar = {
    clickButton:function(btn){
        //your code goes here
    },

    getButtonCount:function(){
        //your code goes here
    }
}
```

Then you can call these reusable functions from test cases.

```
OptionalToolbar.clickButton("Home");
```

This will make the test framework independant from test logic and of course will improve the maintainability and usability (Functions logically grouped by the GUI area they relates to).

I have been using this technique to build my test framework functions and it has proven to be successful over the past 4 years. If you maintain clearly defined layers of functions, you can always adapt changes very quickly.